# How to convert a .py file to .exe with pyinstaller?

Tags: python-3.x, pyinstaller

I would like to create an executable file from a .py- file.
I'm doing this with pyinstaller.exe and it works.
But I've also created another .py-file which cointains some functions and these should be called in the future by my .exe-file.

I've already tried with hooks, --add-data and modifying my .spec-file without success.

I will post my code and maybe someone could tell me, what I'm doing wrong.
My new executable should be created from EMVAT.py and the "extra" functions are in serialutils.py

I enter these commands in my command prompt:

```
pyi-makespec.exe --add-data:E:\V11\utils;serialutils.py EMVAT.py

pyinstaller.exe --onefile EMVAT.py
```

Comment: Normally adding another packae or module to you main script should be no problem. Are you getting any error messages?

Comment: yes, but i can not read the traceback, because the window close with some velocitiy that is just impossible :-((

Comment: Yes you can. Just Start your exe from the command-line

Comment: now, i become a new answer:

Comment: error: unrecognized arguments: --add-data:E:\V11\utils;serialutils.py

Comment: That error gives you enough info to figure it out. There's something wrong with your --add-data argument.